# Selecting block of text until blank line, Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Am trying to select one or more lines  until blank/ empty line is found at the start of the document, which would be the title.Did use the macro recorder the recorded macro uses selection.movedownunit.Not sure what has to be used here as the line could be one or more.WDLine,WDParagraph selects depending on the count parameter(as the number of lines is not constant).
Did use VBNullString,^P^P,("\Blank).empty but throws a error.

The code auto generated is :

```
Sub SelectTillBlankLine()
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=WDLine , Count:=4 , Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Style = WDStyleTitle

End Sub
```

Appreciate any suggestions...

Comment: Did you try any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=Word+vba+empty+line)??  Once you find the next empty line, you can define a `Range` variable to hold the current selection up to the last non-blank line. Then select that `Range`.

Comment: Am not able to accept or upvote your answer , as i make use of a screen reader(NVDA) to access the web. And am not finding the greyed out check box. The screen reader is not able to recognize this.am trying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion best option is to use `.Find object` in this situation. Try with this code (and check some comments below):

```
Sub SelectTillBlankLine()

    'as of current selection we search for anything with two consecutive paragraphs
    'the second one is empty
    Selection.Find.Execute "*^13^13", , , True

    'some correction of range- remove last paragraph from selection
    ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Start, Selection.End - 1).Select

    'the rest of your code
    Selection.Style = WDStyleTitle

End Sub
```

**Tried and tested** for simple document.

Comment: Am not able to accept or upvote your answer , as i make use of a screen reader(NVDA) to access the web. And am not finding the greyed out check box. The screen reader is not able to recognize this.am trying... –